Is 'adjective' always appropriate to classify 'single' in the phrase 'a single [noun]'?
Obviously, single is classed as an adjective in such noun/determiner phrases as

a single woman
a single bed
a single ticket

(the default, collational or compound, readings).
Cambridge Dictionary classes the 'just one' usage as 'adjective' also:

single [adjective]
B2 [before noun] one only:

He knocked his opponent down with a single blow.


So do Merriam-Webster, Collins, OED, Longman, AHD and RHK Webster's.
Though there is admittedly semantic/pragmatic (evaluative; emphasising) content in the above example ([just] one blow) and CD's next examples


not a single: Not a single person offered to help her. (not [even] one person[!])
You haven't been listening to a single word I've been saying. (not [even] one point considered[!])


this does not have to be the case:

A single sparrow could be seen perched in the bush. ('one', but sounds stylistically better).

As 'a few' is generally accepted as a [compound] quantifier (eg from British Council ... English](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/a1-a2-grammar/quantifiers-few-a-few-little-a-bit):


Quantifiers: 'few', 'a few', 'little' and 'a bit of'

Look at these examples to see how these quantifiers are used with
countable and uncountable nouns....

I have a few friends, so I'm not lonely.


Should not 'a single' in such usages be regarded as [an analogue of†] a compound quantifier? [And thus a determiner, or a numeral equivalent like 'a dozen' for those who classify numerals separately.]
†Quantifiers are usually restricted to being non-exact expressions of quantity.

I don't see any reason to say it's not an adjective. Compare "The single sparrow" (if the sparrow has already been mentioned) or "One single sparrow" or "My single sparrow". Are all of these compound quantifiers too?

@StuartF "Not an adjective" should be understood according to a modern point  of view that the characteristic "single" not being inherent to the referent, it becomes appropriate to speak of a different part of speech, which is the determiner (quantifiers are determiners).

You seem to be saying that A single sparrow could be seen perched in the bush isn't "emphatic". But obviously it is, or it would just be a sparrow.

The difference in meaning between A single woman can safely enjoy a drink alone in our bar and Not a single woman can safely enjoy a drink alone in your bar is much more than just the negation. But surely they're both adjectives - just with significantly different meanings.

It's hard to demand emphasis in 'I could see six tulips, a pair of fritillaries, a single red rose, and several snowdrops in the border': I'd argue for a style choice, a softening ('one' is rather stark) especially in, er, flowery prose.

Doesn't this depend greatly on the difference between 'single' and 'singular'?
Either way, I suggest adjectives and numbers are quite separate and the numbers in one woman, nine beds and 37 tickets are not at all adjectival.
I'm not sure this is helpful and to me, if this has anything to do with adjectives, that seems reminiscent of the strange difference between 'articles' and 'determiners…'

... I'd say 'a single' is at least in part a compound numeral [equivalent], like  'a dozen'. There is the adjectival tone also; it is not an 'exact synonym' of 'one'. But its sense is not always the same in every environment.
